# What to do with extra copper wire on light

Tags: wiring

[image]Light has black, white, & green wires & bare copper wire. Ceiling has black, white, and copper wires. What do I do with the extra copper wire?

Comment: I am assuming by copper you mean a bare wire.  If so green and bare/copper are connected together.  They are your safety grounds.

Comment: Remember that we can't see what you see. A picture is worth 1000 words, please [edit] one into your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### That extra bare wire is a grounding wire, so attach it to the other grounding wires

It's not unheard of for light fixtures to have two grounding wires, say one for the fixture itself and the other for a mounting bracket.  Simply treat them as any other grounding wire and lump them in with the rest of the grounding wires.